# SSIS - Remove configuration on project deployment model

Tags: ssis

I have converted my project to Project deployment model. When I was converting there was a checkbox which said “Remove configurations from all packages after conversion" and I did not check it when I shouldn't have. Now all the configurations are part of my local project. Is there a way I could remove all the configurations after the conversion is complete?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this and let me know if it works:

1. Double click on package to open and see its properties in right
   side.
2. Click three dots in configuration as shown in image.
3. Now
   enable the package configuration. It should show your config which
   you can simply delete.

[image: i1]

Comment: I tried that, but it does not show me the configurations that are saved. Thanks for checking, are there any other suggestions?

Comment: These are the configurations the tick box you mentioned in your question was referring to. What other configurations were you referring to that you don't want to be in your project?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I came across the same issue and hoping this will help someone.  I am using Visual Studio 2017 v15.9.11 and SSDT v15.9.0 on Windows 10 Enterprise.  This was done for a package destined for SQL 2016, but I believe it would work on any package for SQL 2012+.

You can remove/disable package configurations after conversion by doing the following:

- Find your dtsx file in Solution Explorer
- Press F7 (or right-click the package > View Code)
- Search for the `<DTS:Configurations>` element and remove the entire section
- Save the file and re-open in designer view.  Right-click the package and "Package Configurations..." should no longer be in the context menu.

Example from one of my packages - this is what was deleted:

```xml
  <DTS:Configurations>
    <DTS:Configuration
      DTS:ConfigurationString="&quot;CONFIG&quot;;&quot;[dbo].[SSIS_CONFIG]&quot;;&quot;YourConfigName1&quot;;"
      DTS:ConfigurationType="7"
      DTS:CreationName=""
      DTS:DTSID="{C2C3EDFC-392A-401F-AC75-4D4C82A9CD68}"
      DTS:ObjectName="Configuration 1" />
    <DTS:Configuration
      DTS:ConfigurationString="&quot;CONFIG&quot;;&quot;[dbo].[SSIS_CONFIG]&quot;;&quot;YourConfigName2&quot;;"
      DTS:ConfigurationType="7"
      DTS:CreationName=""
      DTS:DTSID="{A7F0C4DD-4891-44E1-817A-AB8431DA6509}"
      DTS:ObjectName="Configuration 2" />
  </DTS:Configurations>
```